# Как JSF (Primefaces) вызвать диалог по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Не могу разобраться, как вызвать диалог, подобный этому https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/loginDemo.xhtml
по нажатию на CommandButton? Можно ли это сделать средствами JSF (Primefaces) без использования JS?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю вопрос - вы хотите сделать тоже самое, но только чтобы вызов производился не по нажатию на `outputLink`, а на `commandButton`?

Comment: Да, именно так. По нажатию CommandButton

Comment: Вы, наверное. имели в виду без `onclick="PF('dlg').show();"` ? Поскольку иначе просто заменив одно на другое - все работает.

Comment: Я же написал, без использования JS

Comment: Ок, согласен. Проголосовал за предложенный вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Именно такой и совсем без js нельзя. Но если очень нужно, то можно зайти с другой стороны:

1. Объявляем компонент содержащий div с необходимой разметкой;
2. Навешиваем на этот div стиль, чтобы он выглядел как диалог;
3. Связываем свойство компонента `rendered` с булевым свойством бина;
4. А на свойство `action` кнопки навешиваем метод, изменяющий свойство бина.

Можно ещё `<f:ajax />` добавить, для интерактивности.